# Maven share resource

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I use the "maven-remote-resources-plugin" to share the resource
but,right now file in the "web-inf" folder,
I know,"web-inf" can not be accessed.

how can I put the file into src/main/webapp folder?

child parent POM
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9I8XO.png)

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.5</version>
<configuration>
    <resourceBundles>
        <resourceBundle>test:a-resources:${project.version}</resourceBundle>
    </resourceBundles>
    <outputdirectory>/</outputdirectory>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>process</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

child A POM
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lY9rH.png)

```
<plugins>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>bundle</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <resourcesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</resourcesDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.json</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

### parent (web app)

src/main/webapp

### child A (storage html,js,css file)

--page 
      --index.html

### child B (storage java class file)

--java.class

Comment: Hi Please refer this page for asking good question which usually get upvoted,which helps in getting good answer [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You should take a look via maven-war-plugin (overlays) could help here..

Comment: @khmarbaise I will try...